# Domino Designer sometimes showing no design elements

Tags: xpages

I'm using IBM Domino Designer 9.0.1. I have a server locally installed, and I have an ODP project associated to the nsf. Recently I've been opening Domino Designer to have it completely forget the nsf elements (have a look at the picture). Preferences/General/Workspace is set to 'Refresh automatically' and Build automatically is turned off.

I've tried: Refreh (no effect), Build (no effect), Sync (Progress bar gets filled with 'Updating File Menu based on Navigator Filter' but no progress).

The only thing that seems to work is re-associating the ODP to a new nsf.

Anybody have anything similar? Should I just reinstall Domino Designer? Because, you know, that's just loads of fun!

[image]

Comment: If you do have to reinstall there's a way to export all the preferences and working sets I believe.  I think Paul Withers bloggers about it once.

Comment: David, indeeed he did on http://www.intec.co.uk/quick-setup-restore-of-domino-designer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue but with an older version of Designer (8.5 or 8.01). Currently at 9.01 and haven't had the issue.    I believe I had to [rebuild my /workspace](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/0/107fda9b6ecd777c852576d300760483?OpenDocument) to solve the issue.

I found another [similar issue with 8.01 in the Notes forum](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/7756aedc25e6d81285256324005ac76c/0a61e9e408072214852574c1004e2573?OpenDocument).  You didn't mention if Processing indications (green circle and status bar bottom right) showed anything going on in the background.

Comment: If I tried Sync, I'd get Progress bar gets filled with 'Updating File Menu based on Navigator Filter' but no progress. It's a right old pain in the neck it is. Can't wait for some sort of headless Domino Designer, with external eclipse.

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild your /workspace directory?

Comment: I've rebuilt it, and it works now. I've now taken the habit of saving my domino designer preferences

Answer (score 0):

delete your workspace directory under Data. it saves your day